# ObservableCollection find item match on reference equality

Tags: c#, list, observablecollection

Its late so this may be a dumb question...
If Fish is a class (with no Equal/operator== overrides/overloads) and I want to get a specific fish matched on reference equality from a List or ObservableCollection of Fish(es) currently I do:

```
Fish found_fish1 = my_list.Find(f => f==search_fish);
Fish found_fish2 = my_observable_collection.FirstOrDefault(f => f==search_fish);
```

Is that the best way to do this?  I was expecting an XXXX method that takes a Fish (similar to Remove) eg

```
Fish found_fish = my_observable_collection.XXXX(search_fish);
```

but just can't seem to find it.

Comment: question, is all you want to know is whether or not it exists?  Since search_fish == found_fish, do you really need found_fish?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Good point! - I did mention it was late... If you put that as an answer I'll accept it. (ie just use Contains)

Comment: Nah, Rick beat me to Contains() fair and square :-), thanks for the consideration though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `found_fish` is either `search_fish` or `null`, you can use [`ICollection<T>.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56.aspx):

```
Fish found_fish1 =
    my_list.Contains(search_fish) ? search_fish : null;
Fish found_fish2 =
    my_observable_collection.Contains(search_fish) ? search_fish : null;
```

Comment: Thanks - kind of seems obvious now - must be time for bed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the correct way.

`Find` takes a `Preciate<Fish>`, and `FirstOrDefault` takes a `Func<Fish, bool>`, so your signature will work for both; both signatures expect a single `Fish`, and a return value of boolean.

But since you're really just testing to see if a given fish is in your collection, why not just use `Any()`

```
bool searchFishExists = my_observable_collection.Any(f => f == search_fish);
```